# Need to deploy python file from s3 bucket through jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, cicd

How can I take file from s3 bucket instead of Github
where can I add s3 details in jenkins and which type of project I need to choose
any other best solution instead of jenkins??

Am expecting jenkins takes file from s3 and deploy in eks pod

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of different ways you could do this. There are a number of s3 plugins out there but they don't seem particularly reliable. It is better if you create a regular pipeline and run `s3 cp` commands to pull the image from s3 using bash/batch scripts. You need to first go into your Jenkins host machine, switch to the Jenkins user, and set up you AWS credentials using `aws configure`. Then you need to use:

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region region-code --name my-cluster
```

To setup access to your EKS cluster.

I'm not sure how you plan to deploy a Python file to an EKS cluster since Kubernetes clusters only accept yaml manifests. In your Jenkins job you can use aws cli commands to pull the file from s3, do any processing on the file, use kubectl commands to deploy it to the EKS cluster.